# Memory and Register panels in Visual Studio 2008 missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

When I still had VS2005 there were a Memory and a Register panel available while debugging C/C++ projects. I think they could be activated from the Debug menu, I'm not sure anymore.
The problem is that in VS2008 (Pro) I can't find them nowhere. I thought that it may be some corruption of the program files, but after installing Win7 and all the programs from scratch, they still don't appear :(
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen something similar, where if you've installed SQL Server first, then you get the "Business Intelligence" configuration of Visual Studio, which is missing a bunch of stuff.

Go to `Tools` / `Import and Export Settings...` / `Reset all settings`.

Comment: I reset the settings and choose the C++ ones and now they appear. It was probably because I had the C# settings.

Answer (score 3):

They appear on the Debug menu when you are debugging: Debug->Windows->Register

```
Register = Ctrl+Alt+G

Memory   = Ctrl+Alt+M, 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: They don't appear :( It's so strange.

Comment: When I press for example Ctrl+Alt+M, 1 it says "The key combination (...) is bound to a command which is not currently available). I run the Pro version, not Express, so it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

They ought to be available under Debug / Windows, while you're debugging.